# Build fails when run using gitlab-ci runner which uses docker container

Tags: docker, cmake, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am doing a university project for which I need to a gitlab-ci.yml . So test the gitlab-ci file I installed docker and gitlab runner on my local PC. Now when i run the gitlab runner for the build job, build fails. The reason is, this is a big project which has many library dependencies, and some libraries have ***sudo make install*** in their makefiles.

Usually when I run the build locally (without gitlab runner), at the install step it asks for password to proceed with the installation. But how do I achieve this while running in gitlab runner? Is there a way to make the docker container run as root ?

Please advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some googling around and finally made it to work.

Specifying `sudo` inside docker container which is running as `root` will not work, as `sudo` command was not available. So what I did is create a user called `docker` to run inside docker container and add him to the `sudoers` list. Then the `sudo` command was available and `sudo make install` was successfull !!

Answer (score 0):

Here are the ways to resolve it:

- make build as `root` user
- setup password-less `sudo` so during build time you (scripts) can do `make install` (see how to configure PAM modules)
- it looks like you have a CMake based project, then you can make, say `image/` directory inside your container (any writable location, probably the build directory) and tell to CMake `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<your-build-dir>/image`, then point other porject to search dependencies in the installed image. And you don't need to be `root` for this.

Comment: How to tell the gitlab runner to run the docker container as root so that build can run as root user? my gitlab-ci has the below script, 
  script:
    - cmake .
    - make -j8

also How can gitlab-ci continue executing make -j8 even though cmake command fails ? I want to know this because I am gonna add few more commands to my script